# What will happen if I single step debug a blocked thread?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

What will happen if I use a debugger like `gdb` to attach to a process and use `single step` when the current thread is in the middle of a blocked operation?

For example, the current thread is waiting for `sigwait` to return, and I use `single step`. Will the execution continue, or will it just stop until `sigwait` returns?

Comment: What have you tried? Is the result not expected?

Comment: When you single step into a system call, it will simply wait for the system call to return.

Comment: Practically, I'd expect it would wait for the `sigwait()`.    It's notionally possible that the debugger may cause a signal to be sent to the debugged process that causes `sigwait()` to return - but, I wouldn't expect a debugger to normally do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

> What will happen if I use a debugger like gdb to attach to a process and use single step

On most modern processors, GDB performs `single step` by setting a single-step processor flag, and resuming current instruction. Once that instruction finishes, the processor will raise single-step trap, which will cause the OS to notify GDB that something happened to the inferior (being debugged) process. GDB knows to expect that something (since it remembers that you just did a `stepi`).

> when the current thread is in the middle of a blocked operation?

In that case, the current instruction is a `syscall`, and so the single-step trap will not execute until after the system call completes.

> For example, the current thread is waiting for sigwait to return, and I use single step. Will the execution continue, or will it just stop until sigwait returns?

The latter.

Comment: Does IDA and GDB have different implementation of `Set Breakpoint` ?  AFAIK IDA add breakpoint by insert a `INT 3` instruction. But from your answer it seems that GDB add breakpoint by set flag register ?

Comment: @user16387400 Single-stepping doesn't require inserting a breakpoint on modern processors, but it is used on processors which can't single-step in hardware.